# JQuery Mobile styling not retained on html content from .load()

Tags: php, jquery-mobile, cordova

I scoured the internet for the solutions but none worked for me.

I am using JQuery Mobile + PHP and Phonegap to create a hybrid mobile app. When I try to insert dynamic content the JQuery Mobile styling is not applied to the returned html content.

Here is what I'm working with:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-    scalable=0;" name="viewport" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<title>Barslide</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/Barslide-swatches.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/jquery.mobile.icons.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).on('pageinit', "#home", function() {
$("#home-bar-list-friends").load("php/home-bar-list-friends.php");
$("#home-bar-list-friends").listview("refresh");

});
</script>

</head>
<body>
```

...

```
<ul id="home-bar-list-friends" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="b">
</ul>
```

PHP script: php/home-bar-list-friends.php - static content for testing

```
<?php
echo 
'
  <li><a href="bar.html?id=100">101 Cantina | 11</a></li>
  <li><a href="bar.html?id=101">Grogg House | 9</a></li>
  <li><a href="bar.html?id=102">Tall Pauls | 7</a></li>
  <li><a href="bar.html?id=103">08 Seconds | 4</a></li>
  <li><a href="bar.html?id=104" rel="external">The Swamp | 2</a></li>
</ul>';
?>
```

Comment: I also noticed that other commands like alert() will not execute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I did not include the create event.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#bars', function(){   
$('#bars-list').empty();
$.post('php/bars-list.php',function(bars)
{
    $('#bars-list').append(bars);
    $('#bars-list').trigger('create');
    $('#bars-list').listview('refresh');
})  
});
```